# Angular 2 firebase how to add posts with uid url?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How to create pages only related to the specific data on db ? For example :

1. User creates 3 projects (title, description, photo)
2. User clicks on the projects and inside of it he sees only specific data related to that project.
3. When the User clicks on the other project, it shows only that project information.

The things I know how to do :

1. Create user
2. create user related data in db.

The thing I don't know :

**How to create dynamic pages with angular firebase ?**